# PHP Propel-gen to zend framework naming convention

Tags: php, zend-framework, naming-conventions, propel

I am playing with the build settings in my `build.properties` file for propel (version 1.5.4) but don't get it right.

Example: Table `News` should have

- class `Model_News` in `./Model/News.php`
- class `Model_Base_News` in `./Model/Base/News.php`

My main problems:

- propel adds the project name as a folder between `Model` and `News.php` like: `/Model/project/News.php`
- propel adds the `propel.classPrefix` to the file, too. So `propel.classPrefix = Model_` builds class `Model_News` inside `/Model/project/Model_News.php`

aaaaaaaaaaaahhhh :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can customize the paths to this form by only using `build.properties`. You probably need to overload the `OMBuilder::getClassFilePath()` (used by [`PropelOMTask::build()`](http://www.propelorm.org/browser/tags/1.5.4/generator/lib/task/PropelOMTask.php#L68)) function in [your own custom build classes](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.5/BuildConfiguration#OverridingBuilderClasses). Unfortunately you cannot just override the `OMBuilder` class, but you must create subclasses for all `*Builder` classes.

Comment: Well that sucks. I'll just stick with doctrine and looking forward for doctrine 2.0 to have better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd stick with the Propel conventions and just use the Propel autoloader for Propel classes. Not as clean as your intended solution, perhaps, but I'd not reject an ORM just on the basis of its internal file naming.